# Where Has the 'Shut Down' Option Gone?

Tags: shutdown, gnome

I can't find the 'shut down' option anywhere...

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while menu is open, to show the *Power Off...* option.

I know, that’s a weird decision from GNOME Shell designers...

See [cheat sheet for GNOME Shell](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet) at GNOME Wiki.

Comment: **of course!** How completely stupid of me to even need to ask! /sarcasm :D

Answer (score 5):

By default, there's no shutdown entry in the status menu and you must press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be able to shutdown your computer when using GNOME Shell. But this can be changed by installing Alternative Status Menu extension which adds "Power off" and "Hibernate" to the status menu, visible at all time (and not just when pressing the ALT key). Install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-alternative-status-menu
```

Source: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html